# Output parameters are not populated

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pymssql

I have the following code:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
cursor = conn.cursor()

id_new_field = pymssql.output(int)

res = cursor.callproc('NewField', ('Test',id_new_field))
conn.commit()
conn.close()

print(id_new_field.value)
print(res)
```

Unfortunately my output parameter isn't populated with the id of the field, although the stored procedure is executed correctly. The output ist always 'None'.

I think the problem is, that autocommit ist set to false in my example, am i right?

But i can't set autocommit to true because the stored procedure is raising an error when it isn't executed inside a transaction (It's a vendor SP and i can't alter the SP).

So, my workarount for now is, to use `.execute()` instead of `.callproc()` and writing raw sql into my python script. It's awful. ;)

Is there any chance to use `.callproc()` with autocommit = false?

Or do i have to do it completely different?

Answer (score 0):

I also got `None` when I did

```python
print(id_new_field.value)
```

but I was able to retrieve the value by simply indexing into `res` tuple:

```python
print(res[1])
```

(Tested with Python 2.7.11 and pymssql 2.1.1.)

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm using Python 3.5.1 and pymssql 2.1.2. To be precise: it worked only one time. I also tried it with `print(res)`. The first time i got the id of the new field, but when i ran the script a second time, the result was 'None' again.

Comment: There must be something peculiar about the stored procedure you are running. Certainly the answer to the general question *"Is there any chance to use .callproc() with autocommit = false?"* is "Yes.". You haven't shown us the SQL code you use as a workaround so we have no way of knowing what, if anything, your Python code could do to achieve the same result.

Comment: @stefan2342xx - FYI, it also worked for me with Python 3.5.1 and pymssql 2.1.2, even when I called the SP twice in the same script without a `.commit()` in between. Whatever your problem is, it doesn't look like autocommit is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look at the stored procedure maybe i can reduce de SP to a minimum and post it here. :)